# Checking input in a one line for loop, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, input

```
lines = [input("Enter the number") for i in range(0,100)]
```

I want to break the loop if user enter 7 or any higher number.
Assume the loop to be infinite. Looking for a way to check the input while the user enters it.

I am looking for one line code.

o/p: 1 4 5 2 3 4 2 4 5 6 5 7

Comment: Is 7 or greater supposed to be in the accumulated list... eg... would entering 7 from the get go be `[]` or `[7]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the solution you want.

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 7, iter(lambda: int(input()), None)))
```

[image]

need `itertools`, the built-in module in python.

Comment: Depends if you're allowed `itertools` and whether `7` should be included or not... However, `[(yield int(input())) for i in itertools.repeat(1)])` I wouldn't build a list there... you could just make it something like `iter(lambda: input(input()), None)` ....

Comment: @JonClements thanks for your suggestion, you are so smart!

Comment: If missing off the 7 or greater is okay, then you can even make it no imports and do something absolutely vomit inspiring like: `list(iter(lambda: int(input('enter a number: ')), type('foo', (object,), {'__eq__': lambda self, i: i >= 7})()))` :p

Comment: @JonClements Understandable for integers but will the same concept work for say a string? Say, I wanna break out of loop when user enters done.

Comment: @Manish the two argument iter takes any sentinel and stops when it's equal. So you'd use list(iter(input, 'done'))

Comment: @JonClements Thanks a lot. It really helped a lot. Please keeping helping me further. Means a lot.

Comment: @JonClements and pwxcoo may i know the source of your knowledge. I would like to refer some materials regarding the same.

Comment: @ManishSingh To make it clear, Jon is **not** recommending this sort of coding in a sensible program. He's simply showing that it's possible. Crazy tricks like this should be reserved for stuff like [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf). But if you like that sort of thing, check out our sister site, [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

> I am looking for one line code.

This isn't always the best strategy. Here I suggest a multi-line solution.

To break when a certain value is entered, you can convert your list comprehension to a `for` loop. Use `list.append` to add items to an initialised list. Then `break` when a value meets a specified condition.

Also, as below, remember to convert your input to `int` to allow comparison:

```
lines = []
for _ in range(100):
    x = int(input('Enter the number:'))
    lines.append(x)
    if x >= 7:
        break
```

For an *infinite* loop, you can use `while True`:

```
lines = []
while True:
    x = int(input('Enter the number:'))
    # code as before
```